# Fastest way to search through a list of hashes

Tags: search, hash, lookup

I have a list of sha224 hashes in a .txt file and I need to be able to search through them as fast as possible for a specific hash. Assuming processing power and/or storage space aren't an issue, what would be the fastest way to perform a search?

Comment: There are a lot of considerations.  size, support for inserts updates, deletions.  If the size is huge and inserts are done a database would be a good idea

Comment: What sort of databases would you recommend?

Comment: any database you have at hand or is easy to integrate into your project

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd be providing the hash who's value you'd need to read programmatically.

If you don't know the key ahead of time then you probably want to hash the hashes and "search" there, not really a search since you should be able to do it explicitly.

Comment: I think what you meant was to keep a persistent hash table of all the password hashes. Then a new password coming in to the server can be hashed, then looked up in a single operation (if you store all your password hashes in a database, then the database can do the lookup almost as quickly using its (btree) algorithm.